# xmr-stak-nvidia completely freezing computer

Tags: gpu-mining

I have set up xmr-stak-nvidia do mine monero but when I start the mining process, the computer gets completely useless because it freezes a lot. This is happening on Linux Minx 18.2 and **wasn't** happening when I was using Debian 9.1. 
My nvidia driver version is `375.66`. My graphics devices are:

```
lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"
```

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
>   DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
>   Subsystem: Dell Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
>
> 08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)
>           Subsystem: Dell GK208M [GeForce 920M]
>           Kernel driver in use: nvidia

what is going on? Can this be because of the driver version? I'm using [this](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-nvidia) version of the miner.

Comment: I was using xmr-stak-amd, and I couldn't get my monitor to wake up.  It turns out that the computer was responsive however, since 'q' quit the mining, and `sudo reboot` rebooted the computer.  I thought I'd tell you this in case you were actually experiencing this. This is on Xubuntu 16.04.3.